# Windows Phone 7.1 Video (3GP,MP4) to Audio (MP3) Converter -- ffmpeg on windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio, video, ffmpeg

Is there a way to convert Video (3GP,MP4,etc) files stored in isolated storage of a windows phone 7.1 app to a Audio (MP3) file?

I initially thought ffmpeg can do something like this but I can't find a Windows Phone compatible Wrapper. Is there a library I can use or a similar one?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search reveals this library http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/